# Multiple events in one TKinter control

Tags: python, tkinter

Consider the following minimal TKinter app:

```
import tkinter as tki

def do_something(*args):
    print('{} selected'.format(my_choice.get()))

root_win = tki.Tk()
option_list = ['apple', 'orange']
my_choice = tki.StringVar()
my_choice.set('-- nothing selected --')
script_list = tki.OptionMenu(root_win, my_choice,
                             command=do_something,
                             *option_list)
script_list.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root_win.mainloop()
```

The OptionMenu is initialised and "do_something" is executed as soon as the user makes a selection. So far so good.

Now I want the option list to be refreshed every time the user clicks the OptionMenu:

```
import tkinter as tki
from random import randrange

def do_something(*args):
    print('{} selected'.format(my_choice.get()))

fruit = ['strawberry', 'banana', 'pineapple']

def get_new_choice():
    if len(fruit) > 0:
        new_fruit = fruit[randrange(len(fruit))]
        fruit.remove(new_fruit)
        return new_fruit
    else:
        return 'no more fruit'

def refresh_option_list(*args):
    option_list.append(get_new_choice())
    my_menu = my_om['menu']
    my_menu.delete(0, "end")
    for option in option_list:
        my_menu.add_command(label=option, command = '')

root_win = tki.Tk()
option_list = ['apple', 'orange']
my_choice = tki.StringVar()
my_choice.set('-- nothing selected --')
my_om = tki.OptionMenu(root_win, my_choice,
                             command=do_something,
                             *option_list)
my_om.bind('<Button-1>', refresh_option_list)
my_om.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root_win.mainloop()
```

The "refresh_option_list" is executed every time the contol is clicked and adds another option to the list. Which is nice. But what does not work any more is the "do_something" command, which is not executed any more. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are adding the new option, you wipe the whole menu and build it up again. That's ok, but the problem is that you're also resetting the `command` option for all menu elements, so they stop running the `do_something()` function, and lose the connection to the `my_choice` variable.

One approach you could try is doing this when adding the new options:

```
for option in option_list:
    my_menu.add_command(label=option, command=lambda o=option: do_something(o))
```

That means you connect all the options to `do_something()`, and pass to it which option it is. You should note the use of a [`lambda` function](https://pythonprogramming.net/passing-functions-parameters-tkinter-using-lambda/).

Then, you have change `do_something()` a bit, to emulate the connection to the `my_choice` variable:

```
def do_something(option):
    my_choice.set(option)
    print('{} selected'.format(my_choice.get()))
```

---

One other thing I'd consider doing, is removing the `my_om.bind('<Button-1>', refresh_option_list)` line, and simply adding a call to `refresh_option_list()` at the end of `do_something()`, but that depends on what you're trying to effectively achieve, so that may not be what you'd need.

Comment: That worked, thanks! The example wasn't really representative of the actual code, it just served to illustrate the problem. Therefore putting the refresh into the selection command is not an option.